# Java SHA not woking. Hash value dosen't equal String. Is there an issue with my encoding?

Tags: java, hash, java-security

Basically I have this

```
   if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java MyMd5 <message>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        // get message
        byte[] message = args[0].getBytes("UTF8");
        // create message digest object for MD5
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        // System.out.println("Provider: " +
        messageDigest.getProvider().getInfo();
        // create message digest
        messageDigest.update(message);
        byte[] md = messageDigest.digest();
        // print result
        System.out.println("Message Digest Algorithm: MD5");
        System.out.println("Message: " + new String(message));
        System.out.println("Message Digest: \"" + new String(md, "UTF8") + "\"");
        String HashPassword=new String(md, "UTF8");
        System.out.println(HashPassword);
        System.out.println(HashPassword.equals("???8p???W?B:??N?~"));
```

but somehow when I try to compare it is returning false. Is it some problem with my encoding? Thanks!

```
    Message Digest Algorithm: MD5 
    Message: pass123
    Message Digest: "???8p???W?B:??N?~"
    ???8p???W?B:??N?~
    false
```

Comment: The main problem is that you are converting between byte arrays and strings, pretending in several places that the byte array contains UTF-8 encoded text, while in reality it's not encoded text at all.

Comment: `?` means an unprintable char, so `?` does not necessarily equals `?` - compare on a byte level

Comment: "Java MD5 not woking.": you noticed how unlikely this is? MD5 in Java is around for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with unnecessary encoding, with md5 we have to encode the String in the correct way instead of using UTF8 encoding

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String pass = "pass123";
    byte[] message = pass.getBytes();
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    messageDigest.update(message);
    byte[] md = messageDigest.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < md.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((md[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    System.out.println("encoded pass:" + sb.toString());
    System.out.println(sb.toString().equals("aafdc23870ecbcd3d557b6423a8982134e17927e"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to compare newly generated hash string with existing one (stored in a data base or somewhere else). It's possible with provided above code and you will get `true` if you store generated value (not copy it from console) to the data base for example, and then compare it with newly generated.

But when you generate hash it contains symbols (characters), that doesn't have correct representation in any String encoding. So, nobody don't store hashes as a plain strings. Usually they are stored in `hex string` representation or `Base64` representation.

Implementation with the use of `hex strings` provided below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { // args = ["Hello world"]
if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Usage: java MyMd5 <message>");
    System.exit(1);
}
// get message
byte[] message = args[0].getBytes("UTF8"); //You may have problems with encoding here. In Windows, for example, with symbols that are out of English alphabet range  
// create message digest object for MD5
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
// System.out.println("Provider: " +
messageDigest.getProvider().getInfo();
// create message digest
messageDigest.update(message);
byte[] md = messageDigest.digest();
System.out.println("Digest: " + byteArrayToHexString(md));
System.out.println("Is equals? " + byteArrayToHexString(md).equals("7b502c3a1f48c8609ae212cdfb639dee39673f5e"));
}

private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(array.length);
    IntStream.range(0, array.length)
        .forEach(i -> result.append(Integer.toString( (array[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)));
    return result.toString();
}
```

Also, in provided example mentioned that you are using `MD5`, but actually it's `SHA`. `MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");`